# Django South: Migrating FK from another table

Tags: python, django, migration, django-south

I was doing some system and my table design was like this:

```
Table A:
   - ID
   - ForeignKey(C)

Table B:
   - ID
   - ForeignKey(A)

Table C:
   - ID
```

Due to some requirement changes, I need to move ForeignKey(C) from A to B, so it goes like this:

```
Table A:
    - ID

Table B:
    - ID
    - ForeignKey(A)
    - ForeignKey(C)

-Table C:
    - ID
```

The schema migration was easy. But last time I already have some existing FK data in table A. Which I can't just delete right away. I need to migrate this FK's to table B. The structure of B is different as well as it's data inside. When I add ForeignKey(C) to B's model, South was asking me for a default value because I didn't provide any default value and it is not allowing NULL. The choice was to quit schemamigration and add default value manually or provide 1-time value.

My question is, how can I add default/1-time value that is imported from existing data in table A using South?. I was searching for this similar problem but no luck :(

Thanks.

Comment: South developers may give you a better approach but as mush as I explore there is no such support.

Answer (score 6):

When doing this type of migration I always create 3 migrations:

1. creates the new field
2. (a datamigration) copies the data from the old field to the new field (possibly with a transformation)
3. deletes the old field

This way I can use the auto schemamigration from south for the first and the third migration and only have to write some simple conversion code. This works like [this example](http://south.aeracode.org/docs/tutorial/part3.html) in the south tutorial.